# Detecting memory fragmentation problem in a process

Tags: c, memory-fragmentation

What are the various mechanisms using which we can detect if a process execution is leading to memory fragmentation?

Are there any tools available for the same? Suggestion for tools which work with 'C' code and can run on Windows, Linux and VxWorks will be helpful.

Comment: On which platform should said tools run?

Comment: Thanks for the question. I have edited and updated my question.

Comment: Same question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386776/memory-fragmentation-profiler

Comment: on Solaris, malloc_stats function can be used (need to be called from inside the process, either code it in or call by attaching to GDB). Unfortunately on Linux systems this might NOT return correct value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as a suggestion, you may want to try Valgrind.  I'm not certain it's what you're looking for, but it may come in handy.

http://valgrind.org/

Answer (score 1):

There is a maxfreeblocksize in vxworks, if it keeps gettin lower and lower its an indication its getting fragmented

Answer (score 0):

On linux you can see the output of:

```
cat /proc/buddyinfo
```

It tells how many pages of a given order are available. If there are very few higher order pages available and mostly lower order pages are available and it indicates your system memory is quite fragmented. Look for the "Normal" entry.

See [proc.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt)