# from gdb core, find largest available block of memory

Tags: gdb, fragmentation, core-file

I have a core of process from a system that kills a process if it allocates memory above a configured limit.
It seems the process crashed because memory is fragmented.
To confirm I want to know largest available free block of memory.
Is there a way I can find it from a core.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386776/memory-fragmentation-profiler

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you are using Linux glibc, gdb plugins such as [libheap](https://github.com/cloudburst/libheap), [gef](https://github.com/hugsy/gef), [pwndbg](https://github.com/pwndbg/pwndbg) provides functionalities of inspecting the free chunks.

Also if you can make the OOM re-happen, you can try some memory allocator that have the functionality to pretty print the malloc arena layout by itself before it crashes (including [jemalloc](http://jemalloc.net/), see [Use Case: Basic Allocator Statistics](https://github.com/jemalloc/jemalloc/wiki/Use-Case:-Basic-Allocator-Statistics))

[Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/quick-start.html) may help if memory leaks, but I am not sure it is useful for memory fragmentation.